# Adding a Customized Button to a Processing Page [Acumatica]

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to customise an Acumatica Processing Page by adding my own processing button. I have tried the usual methods of extending the processing page but unfortunately the button is not displayed on the page.

```
public class APPrintChecks_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPrintChecks>    
{
    public PXAction<APPayment> Test;

    [PXProcessButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Button Test")]
    protected virtual IEnumerable test(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

I do not want to override the existing functionality provided by the processing button and as such would like to add my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary view of the Process Payments / Print Checks page is Filter which is of type `PrintChecksFilter`. So you need to have your `PXAction` on that `Type`. Try to replace

```
public PXAction<APPayment> Test;
```

with

```
public PXAction<PrintChecksFilter> Test;
```